# XML validation in Qt

Tags: xml, qt, xmlschema

How does one validate an XML document against an XML schema in Qt? There must be Qt facilities to do that, but I am unable to find them...

I am using the latest Qt version (6.2.4).

Comment: I haven't checked if this still works for Qt6, but Qt5 has an example app that shows how to validate a schema [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxmlpatterns-schema-example.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Bad news**

I have recently been looking into xml patterns using Qt and unfortunately it seems that QtXmlPatterns was available until Qt 5.13 where it was deprecated and completely removed from Qt 6.x.

See [Qt Xml Patterns 5.15.11](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxmlpatterns-index.html).

I have seen other suggestions online to implement [xerces-C++](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/index.html).